# Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : scan() expected 'an integer', got '*'

Tags: r

I am still learning R, and I am trying to import a .Dat file  using `read.fortran()` from R. Data are from a survey that was conducted using `CSPro`. I am getting the following error message : `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :  scan() expected 'an integer', got '*'`

I have used `read.fortran()` to open another .Dat file from  CSPro and it worked well. It seems to be a problem with the data type. I have explored the file, and I have found "*".

```
exported <- read.fortran("C:/My Documents/Data/ 2000/Exported.dat",c"A25","I8","A6","A25","A25","I1","I1","I1","A20","I2","A5","I2","A20","I1","A20","A25","I1","I1","I2","I2","I1","I2","A30","A11","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","A6","A45","I1","A5","A45","I1","I1","I3","I3","I1"))
```

I was expecting to get a dataframe called `exported` but I am seeing the following error :

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'an integer', got '*'
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to replicate your error but I think there was a missing parenthesis in your code. 
Where your vector begins there should be a '('. I have added it, please try it.

```r
exported <- read.fortran("C:/My Documents/Data/ 2000/Exported.dat",c("A25","I8","A6","A25","A25","I1","I1","I1","A20","I2","A5","I2","A20","I1","A20","A25","I1","I1","I2","I2","I1","I2","A30","A11","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","I1","A6","A45","I1","A5","A45","I1","I1","I3","I3","I1"))
```

Please let me know, if the error still persists.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I forgot to include the parenthesis, but that was not the problem.

Comment: Many of the columns in the data file are integer type. If you can find out '*' appears in which column, then may be reading it as A1 or A2 or A3 ..etc (depending upon how wide is that column) will help. This is a guesstimate suggestion without knowing much about the intended purpose of the read file. Later if needed you can convert the * to NA and then convert that particular column back to integer. This is as far as I can think.

Comment: Thanks Amit, I have found the * , and removed them from the file. This seems to work I am able to open the data set now :)

Comment: Great that your problem is solved. Hiwever, will your columns/data not shift leftwards, if you just remove the '*' rather than keeping it and read differently. May be it will not matter but just a thought. All the best.